# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: datavisualization

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I enabled the data visualization module in the maintenance tool while installing Qt but when I try adding `datavisualization` to the .pro file I get the error message as in the title. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this so could someone please help me out with this?

PS: I had also selected the checkbox for installing the `charts` module in the maintenance tool but that didn't work either. I had to run `sudo apt install libqt5charts5 libqt5charts5-dev`
 for it to work

Comment: install libqt5datavisualization5-dev and libqt5datavisualization5

Comment: i get an `unable to locate package` error. do i have to add some ppa ?

Comment: What version of ubuntu and Qt are you using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04. Running `qmake --version` gives me `QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and my Qt creator version is 4.9.2.

Comment: I initially had an [older version] (https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html) of Qt creator installed. Since that version did not have `charts` and `datavisualization` modules in its maintenance tool dialog box, i uninstalled using the maintenance tool and installed Qt from the official site.

Comment: Do not use several ways to install Qt at the same time, or use a maintenance tool or use apt-get, not both, if you do so you will have these problems.

Comment: I used the maintenance tool for both cases in my previous comment to handle installing and uninstalling. I used apt-get only for the charts since it did not work with the maintenance tool.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the old config folder `Qt` from `~/.config` and re-installing Qt did the trick. Both QCharts and Qdatavisualization work flawlessly without any `apt-get` installation !